# AEM 6.2 - i18n translations not working in Publish env but works in Author

Tags: aem

We are seeing i18n issue only on publish env. Its working fine in author environment. Issue is that i18n is not loading in publish env, due to which i18 translations are not working on AEM pages.

Author -   http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/i18n/dict.en_us.json - i18n loads fine

Publisher  - https://localhost:4503/libs/cq/i18n/dict.en_us.json  - Error saying- Cannot serve request to /libs/cq/i18n/dict.en_us.json on this server  (fyi – I am logged as admin user here)

Troubleshooting till now –

1. Verified all the bundles are active
2. Also, we came to know that i18n is not working for geometrixx pages in publish env

Could someone provide any pointers to fix this?

Comment: Any publish instance error log for your request ?

Comment: nothing in error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the publish server and try. There is a bug since AEM 6.1 that requires a server restart to pick up a new i18n dictionary folder after it is installed on the instance. Subsequent additions to the folder work fine as long as the i18n root folder is not deleted.

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-4814

Comment: We re-started the server earlier but no luck. (i saw above link before.).